# How to stop referencing .rgb files when converting from .OBJ to .GLB (Python)?

Tags: python, scripting, export

I'm trying to make a web application which consists of a file converter(From .OBj to .GLB) as a
feature. Everything works except I realised that when I input a .OBJ and .MTL file, the output
will be a .GLB file with textures even though I did not input a .rgb file.

Here is my conversion workflow:

Users input file through form input and click submit -> files move to an empty`C:/Project/converter/` folder ->
execute python script(`C:/Project/public/converter.py`) on that folder->Blender will import and export it back to the original folder(`C:/Project/converter/`)->return
the converted file back as a download.

I have a .rgb file at `C:/Project/public/upload/models/name/model.rgb` which I realised was causing
the conversion to have textures. After removing it, the same .obj and .mtl file will only
output a .glb file with no textures. What I don't really understand is why Blender(Or my program)
is referencing a .rgb file not even from the same folder. Is there a way to fix this?

Here's my Blender conversion script:

```
import bpy
import os
import sys

name=sys.argv[1] # OBJ file name
outExt=sys.argv[2] #Output extension
inExt=sys.argv[3] #Input Extension
path=sys.argv[4] #Output Path



for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    ob = ob.type == 'MESH' and ob.name.startswith("Cube")   #Remove Default cube
bpy.ops.object.delete()

fullpath = os.path.join(path, name)
name=name[:-4] #Remove extension

Input = getattr(bpy.ops.import_scene, inExt)(filepath=fullpath)

if (outExt=='glb'):
    file_out=os.path.join(path,name)
    Output = getattr(bpy.ops.export_scene, 'gltf')(filepath=file_out)

else:
    name=name+'.'+outExt
    file_out=os.path.join(path,name)
    Output = getattr(bpy.ops.export_scene, outExt)(filepath=file_out)
```

I am using Laravel (PHP) to develop my web app and I will gladly provide more code if needed.

Comment: Is this issue occurring when you run the program standalone or when you are simulating user input via the browser? Is it possibly something related to browser cache that's hanging on to an old version of your project folder hierarchy?

Comment: @Jakemoyo I haven't tested the script since I tried modifying and running it but ran to a Permission error when inputting the file. I did try to manually import and export the same OBJ files myself on Blender using the same directories and the exported .GLB doesn't have the texture files on it. It doesn't feel like it's related to browser cache since it doesn't explain why removing a .rgb file from a different directory will solve the problem. Before I run the export script it will also clean the conversion folders as well.